# trying to get data through payload but payload is not the response but request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, reducers

I have an action that looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_LOCATIONS = 'GET_LOCATIONS';

export function fetchLocals() {

    const request = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    return {
        type: GET_LOCATIONS, 
        payload: request
    };
}
```

here is my reducer for this action:

```
import { GET_LOCATIONS } from '../actions/skyscannerActions.js';

export default function(state=[], action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_LOCATIONS: 
            return [action.payload.data]; 
    }
    return state;
}
```

I cant get the data since my payload is not the response but request, how can I get the response.data from my reducer?

is that eeven possible?

Comment: Make use of thunk middleware and dispatch the response instead of the promise

Comment: how can I do that, is nt there another way? like just ding payload.then()??

Comment: You must keep your reducers pure, also using thunk middleware with async action gives you much more flexibility like dispatching multiple actions so that you can track error, success and loading conditions

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri do you know how to get rid of this: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "redux-form"`

Comment: If you are referring to the Duplicate question and using redux-form, you don't need it. It was used by the OP. However you need to install it before usnig with `npm install -S redux-form`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri can we chat ?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i keep getting different errors,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164556/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-s-n).

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri did you leave?